# ObjectAnimator animation not shown in UI when used in Fragement with ViewPager

Tags: android, animation, android-fragments, gridview, xamarin

Recently I started playing around with the `ObjectAnimator` in order to add a custom progress information animation.

- I have two Fragments (`FragmentA`, `FragmentB`) containing a GridView
  instance. Both are bound to different collections in the view model
  using adapters (BaseAdapter`).
- `FragmentA` is visible at the beginning. A button is available in
  this fragement to add items to the collection bound to `FragmentB` (e.g.
  active jobs). 
  Both fragments are presented in a `android.support.v4.view.ViewPager`.
- The `FragmentB` listens to the `CollectionChanged` event and adds
  following progress animation (sort of vertical progress bar) to the
  item (the `GridView` child item).

But the animation is not shown in the UI (if I switch to this fragment B in the ViewPager). The grid item's background (the `ClipDrawable`) is not animated in the UI. But events like AnimationStart, AnimationEnd, Update, etc. are raised by the `ObjectAnimator`.

```
private void AddAnimation(long duration, View view)
{
    var background = (LayerDrawable)view.Background;
    var clip = background.FindDrawableByLayerId(Resource.Id.bgclip) as ClipDrawable;

    if (clip != null)
    {
        var animator = ObjectAnimator.OfPropertyValuesHolder(
           clip, 
           PropertyValuesHolder.OfInt("level", 10000, 0));
        animator.SetTarget(clip);
        animator.SetDuration(duration);
        background.SetDrawableByLayerId(Resource.Id.bgclip, clip);
        animator.Start();
    }
}
```

With `bgclip` being the part of a `<layer-list>`.

```
<item android:id="@+id/bgclip">
    <clip
            android:clipOrientation="vertical"
            android:gravity="bottom"
            android:drawable="@drawable/bg_shape"/>
</item>
```

Comment: check if this Animator works for you:  http://pastebin.com/b4ENezLW, if yes probably `OfPropertyValuesHolder` is a culprit